# Remove default controller from auth

Tags: python, web2py

So my main controller is default.py which isn't a big problem
I'm calling my auth in user.py controller which uses the

```
form=auth()
```

Going to /myapp/user redirects to /myapp/default/index/login

I want it to go to /myapp/user/login instead

I have a routes.py to get the /default out of the homepage but that doesn't work for the auth()

Routes.py

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = 'myapp',
        default_controller = 'default',
        default_function = 'index',
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is tricky working with Auth when you put the main action in a controller other than the controller that contains your "index" page. You can tell Auth you are using a different controller, but then it assumes your home page is the "index" action in the same controller as Auth. This requires you to override a number of default settings.

First, tell Auth which controller and function to use for the Auth action:

```
auth = Auth(db, controller='user', function='user')
```

Then change a number of the default settings:

```
default_url_index = URL('user', 'index')
url_index = URL('default', 'index')
for setting in auth.settings:
    if auth.settings[setting] == default_url_index:
        auth.settings[setting] = url_index
```

Now your Auth URLs will look like /myapp/user/user/login, etc. To remove the "user" function name from the URLs, you have to update routes.py to indicate that "user" is the default function in the "user" controller:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = 'myapp',
        default_controller = 'default',
    ),
    myapp = dict(
        default_function = dict(
            default = 'index',
            user = 'user')
        ),
        functions = dict(
            default = ['index', 'list', 'of', 'functions'],
            user = ['user']
        ),
    )
)
```

The above specifies the default functions separately for the "index" and "user" controllers. Also, note that when specifying default functions, it is also useful to specify the list of functions in each controller -- that way if the URL includes any args after the function name, the routing system will be able to disambiguate (this is necessary in the case of the Auth "user" function, as it always includes at least one URL arg after "user" in order to identify the particular Auth action being requested).

Comment: Note, I submitted a ticket requesting an additional argument to `Auth()` so you won't have to change all the default settings when putting the Auth action in a different controller from the index page.